# Awaited task ended in Canceled state does not throw

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Reading [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) by Stephen Toub I'm trying to see how cancellation works for tasks.
In the section *Consuming the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern* under **Await**, in 3-rd paragraph it says:

> If the Task or Task TResult> awaited ended in the Canceled state, an
>   OperationCanceledException will be thrown.

I'm trying to see this in action in the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

   Task<int> valueTask = DoStuffAsync(cancellationToken);
   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

   Console.WriteLine("value task's status: {0}", valueTask.Status); 
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the `DoStuffAsync()` method

```
static async Task<int> DoStuffAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
    return 42;
}
```

Executing this code doesn't throw any exception, it just prints:

> value task's status: Cancelled

Now, my expectation was in `DoStuffAsync()` method since `await Task.Delay(...)` is cancelled, we have awaited task ended in Canceled state, hence exception should have been thrown (according to quote from the TAP document), but if I put a breakpoint on `Console.ReadLine()` and check `valueTask` it's Status is Cancelled, and Exception is `null`.

Can anybody help me understand if I misread the document, or code I come up with is not properly reproducing the case?

Comment: The quote talks about what happens when you await a cancelled task. You *never await the task*! Nobody said `Task.Exception` would have an exception, that's just silly :) You have to understand that you have two separate threads of execution here, and you never synchronize them - where exactly would you expect the exception to happen? On the thread pool, killing your entire application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method returns the task itself and the result itself is never accessed. If you would try to access `valueTask.Result`, you would get a `TaskCanceledException` (inside an AggregateException).

Likewise, if you would `await valueTask` (Main would have to by async), you would try to obtain the result in which case the exception would also be thrown. This is the behaviour described in the mentioned paragraph.

The clue is that the Task object is valid, but the result is not because the code after await is never executed if the task is cancelled. For example with:

```
static async Task<int> DoStuffAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var delay = Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
    Console.WriteLine("before await"); 
    await delay;
    Console.WriteLine("after await"); 
    return 42;
}
```

The second writeline is never executed if the task is cancelled. 
As long as no result is accessed of the task returned by `DoStuffAsync`, the task is a valid object, just cancelled. Accessing the result will force the runtime to acknowledge that the task was never finished and throw an exception.

If the async method does not return a task, you would also get a TaskCancelled Exception:

```
static async void Main()
{
   CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

   DoStuffAsync(cancellationToken);
   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
   Console.ReadLine();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
static async void DoStuffAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
}
```

Because there is no task object to be returned which can contain the status, the compiler has to warn the executing code that it could not completely run the asynchronous code and an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You will get `OperationCanceledException` when you will try to get result from this task.

Try to add this line in the end of your `Main` method:

```
valueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and you will get `TaskCanceledException` that is desendent from `OperationCanceledException`, `await` of canceled task also will throw `TaskCanceledException`.

You can also use `valueTask.Result` and `valueTask.Wait()` but they will throw `AggregateException` with single member `TaskCanceledException`.

For better understanding of what's happening inside `await` it may be useful to see how it's transformed into state machine at [tryroslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#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).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, initially it wasn't clear but after reading @Me.Name's answer now it makes sense & thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer is for the case where you want to use the `TaskCanceledException` inside of your `Task`, but your question is about getting it outside of it but it may still be useful to some. ;-)

In your `Task` (`DoAsyncStuff` function) you have to check the `CancellationToken` and then throw the `TaskCanceledException` by yourself or just call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on it.